# Where is the Immigration check Mumbai-Paris-Cincinatti?

Tags: usa, cdg, student-visas

I am a student with a F1 visa. I am traveling back from Mumbai to Cincinnati. I have a layover in CDG (Paris) and later directly to Cincinnati. Where will the Immigration be done in this case?

Comment: Are you asking if you need a transit visa in France?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket?

Answer (score 6):

Provided both flights are on the same ticket and you fly on the Paris-Cincinnati direct flight:

- In Mumbai, the airline will check that you have the required documentation to:

  - Transit France airside
  - Enter the USA
    They will also send the data to the US CBP.
    Since you have a valid visa for the US, this is enough to allow both airside transit in France (otherwise you would need an Airport Transit Visa) and for entry into the US.
    Your hold luggage will be “checked-through” to your final destination, you won’t see it until Cincinnati.
- In Paris, you will not go through regular French passport control as you won’t be entering France. They may perform checks right at the aircraft door. In some cases people from citizenships requiring ATVs are escorted to a secure area and then on to their next flight, no idea if that could apply to you (I wouldn’t think so). You will not see your checked luggage.
- There is no US preclearance in France.
- In Cincinnati you will go through passport control, retrieve your bags and go through customs.